# Display CPT UI Posts by ID

Tags: html, wordpress, posts, timber

(Sorry for my english, i'm trying to not use Google Translate ^^)

So.. I created a CPT UI "projets" which contain actually 2 posts (FMXD and Siemens) as you can see here :

[image: SETS]

I want that when i click on FMXD, i have a first page only displaying the post_thumbnail of FMXD. Like This :[image: thumbnail]

As you can see, my page is displaying FMXD and Siemens and i don't understand why...

Actually, i have a single-projets.php :

```html
<?php

/*
Template Name: Projets
Template Post Type: post, page, product, projets
*/

$context = Timber::get_context();

$posts = Timber::get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'projets',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',

) );

$context['posts'] = $posts;

Timber::render( [ 'single-projets.twig'], $context );
?>
```

and a single-projets.twig :

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% for post in posts  %}
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="imgProjets">
                        <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src }}"  alt="">
                    </div>
                <div class=" offset-9 col-3 title">
                    <a href="{{ post.link }}">
                        {{ post.title }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-9 col-3">
                    {{ post.meta('clients') }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="offset-9 col-3 bg-light text-dark">
                    See the projects
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

And after that, i want to click on "See the projets" and see the content of FMXD OR Siemens, and not both.

Sorry it was quit long, but i really need your help, i'm really blocked....

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of code you might want in `archive-projets.php`, but not in a template for a *single* post.

This part:

```php
$posts = Timber::get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'projets',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',

) );

$context['posts'] = $posts;
```

is getting all `projets` posts and passing them to the view to be rendered in a loop.

You can replace that entire part with:

```php
$context['post'] = new Timber\Post();
```

You don't need a loop in your Twig view at all, since there's only one post to render. So just remove `{% for post in posts  %}` and the corresponding `{% endfor %}`.